# bokeh server: loading and waiting for localhost

Tags: python, server, bokeh

I have the myapp.py file in http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

when i run the command, bokeh serve --show myapp.py, the web page http://localhost:5006/myapp keeps loading and says "waiting for localhost..." at the bottom left corner.

here is what I have on the terminal:

```
$ bokeh serve --show myapp.py
2017-05-19 16:17:38,551 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.5
2017-05-19 16:17:38,557 Starting Bokeh server on port 5006 with applications at paths ['/myapp']
2017-05-19 16:17:38,558 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 25599
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado 4.5 came out after the last Bokeh release and introduced a breaking change to all versions of Bokeh up to `0.12.5`. You can either:

- update your Bokeh version to `0.12.6`, or
- downgrade Tornado to < 4.5